# How to measure by c code

Tags: gpu, benchmarking

I have a question about how to measure the bandwidth of a GPU. I have tried some different ways but none of them work. For example, I tried to use the amount of data transfer divided by the time used to calculate the bandwidth. However, since GPU can switch warps currently executed, the number of data transfer varies during execution. I wonder whether you may give me some advices about how to do it. That would be really appreciated.